# "Illegal block entry" with YAML monsters example in yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, static-libraries, yaml, yaml-cpp

I am running the example found [here](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/wiki/HowToParseADocument) to try out using YAML in C++. I copied the code verbatim into test.cpp in a new project folder.  I compiled YAML into a static library and am linking it to my project.  I'm running Ubuntu 11.10.  I use the following command to compile:

```
    g++ -Wall -I. -g test.cpp -lyaml-cpp -L.
```

I get the following error statement:

```
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YAML::ParserException'
       what(): yaml-cpp: error at line 4, column 2: illegal block entry
    Aborted
```

What is the meaning of this exception?  And what could be wrong?  I couldn't find a clear documentation for what each of the exceptions could mean, so even a link to this information would be helpful.  I am probably out of my depth, as I am new to YAML, using libraries, and linux for that matter.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: The error occurs before "parser.GetNextDocument(doc)".  Also, I ran a simpler example from the website that stores a single scalar, and that worked fine.  Is the exception about my input file, or my code?

Comment: Can you use a debugger to find out where in the example code this occurs?

Comment: Thanks David, I edited the main post to answer your question.

Comment: Which example are you using? (There are several examples listed on that page.)

Comment: The "monster" example.  Sorry for not clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that there's a problem with the input file (`monsters.yaml`). Make sure you copied it *exactly*. It claims there's an error at line 4, column 2, so you can look at that spot first (but yaml-cpp isn't great with location of errors, so that may not be the right spot to look at).

Things to make sure about:

- spaces, not tabs
- the proper number of spaces for indentation